# Angular subscription allowed in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular

In most of the tutorials I've been following, they say to always do a subscription within the constructor ie:

```
constructor(private eventDetailsService: EventDetailsService) {
      this.subscription1 = this.eventDetailsService.reload$
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.eventDetail = response;
            });
}
```

And then to destroy the subscription within ngDestroy:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
    }
```

I have a particular component where I need to do some logic within `ngOnInit` first to workout whether I need to call the subscription in the first place. It allows me to do the subscription within `ngOnInit` without any errors, but I was wondering if there is a consequence of doing this?

```
ngOnInit() {
   if ((this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.parent.params.eventId != undefined))
        {
            this.subscription1 = this.eventDetailsService.reload$
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.eventDetail = response;
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: I would advice you not to put code in the constructor of the component. `ngOnInit` runs before the page has rendered and is perfect for this kind of problems.

Comment: There is no problem if you subscribe to observables later in components lifecycle. The most important thing, like you mentioned, is to do the unsubscribing.

Comment: @StPaulis There is nothing wrong with initialising `subscription` within the constructor, which would otherwise have the consequence of having to add `undefined` (scrict mode ) to the type of `subscription`

Comment: @MikeS. so probably best to do a subscription within the constructor when you can, otherwise within ngOnInit if you have to?

Comment: If you don't need any logic to do the assignment, then that's exactly what the constructor is for. Otherwise your code probably belongs to `ngOnInit()`. The very least you can do is to initialise `subscription` with `new Subscription()` to avoid having to leave it `undefined` in the constructor

Comment: @MikeS. thanks for your reply. I don't have any logic within my other components which have subscriptions so I'll keep them as they are in that case. This is the only component where I need to do a check of some logic beforehand. I tried: private subscription1: new Subscription(); but it doesn't like that.

Comment: It's `private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();` - {access modifer} {variable name}: {Variable Type}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's good practice to subscribe in the onInit() method.
I would recommend to use your constructor only to declare your dependency injections.
In this particular case though, you might run into an error when you leave your component since there's a possibility that your subsciption equals undefined when you call on destroy (you put your code in a if statement).
You can declare your params as an observable to prevent this:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        const eventId$ = this.route.parent.parent.params.pipe(
            map((params: Params) => params.get('eventId')),
            filter(id => !!id)
        );
        this.subscription = eventId$.pipe(
            mergeMap(() => this.eventDetailsService.reload$())
        ).subscribe(response => {
            this.eventDetail = response;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

By doing so, your observable will only emit when you have the eventId param in your route and your subscription is safe to be unsubscribed once you destroy the component.
Also, If you navigate to the same component with a different eventId param, this observable will emit the new eventId value and retrigger your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To keep the code the same couldn't I just be lazy and write?
if ((this.subscription1 != null))
        {
            this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
        } within ngOnDestroy?

Comment: yes, it totally works as well but I would write it like that: 
`if (!!this.subscription1) { this.subscription1.unsubscribe(); }`
Your subscription would be equal to `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

It is even good practice to put your `Subscription`s into the `ngOnInit()`, as you want to initialize the data as soon as possible and display data directly when you access the component and update the UI.

There are no consequences, as you already `.unsubscribe()` in your `ngOnDestroy()` step.

Comment: Please do not only downvote, but provide a reason on why